# scala - best way to do parallel constant polling and processing

Tags: multithreading, scala

I am trying to figure out what is the best way to do constant polling in async and non blocking way. Entire goal of the application is to start few threads and with each thread do constant polling on external service (kafka) to get data; each thread then can process that data or hand it over to some other thread. I don't see a way to do this just with scala `Future` as it requires `timeout` value. I can set it to a  year but that still doesn't seem like a good solution. e.g. `Await.result(future, 365 days)` Any pointers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of Async Non-Blocking Kafka libraries. You can write a consumer in any of these to pull data from Kafka topics.

https://github.com/cakesolutions/scala-kafka-client

https://github.com/akka/reactive-kafka